# Powershell set execution policy back to restricted?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I installed chocolaty individual, so added execution policy to `AllSigned` from `Restricted` and I would like to go back to `Restricted` again. But the chocolaty install command set it to `Bypass` and it got PermissionDenied on `Set-ExecutionPolicy` command.

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by
a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective
execution policy of Bypass. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more
information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

How to set it back to Restricted and is it needed to set it back to restricted or something else?

Comment: `PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Scope Process -Force`

Comment: The error message gives you all the answers you are looking for. Just read it carefully and clarify your question: There are three scopes for execution policies: machine, user and process. You did not specify at which scope you changed it to `AllSigned` and you did not specify at which scope it was changed by choco.

Comment: Just to be clear, Chocolatey didn't set it to Bypass permanently. The install command for Chocolatey currently is `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; ....` It sets the execution policy for the _current running process_ (this is defined by the `-Scope Process` parameter), which is the command it is running, to Bypass. Your session execution policy will be unchanged if you run the command as provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted -Scope Process -Force
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!